# How do you open the Windows Command prompt using eclipse with java programming?

Tags: java, eclipse, window, external, command-prompt

I am creating a text based program/ game and someone I know created one that opened the console into the Windows Command prompt. This made it so it could be continually refreshed, making the text clear and having a clean look, rather than the clunky console view, which just adds the text onto it, making a bad medium for a text-based game.

Comment: i don't know if this is what you are looking for, but anyways you might want to have a look at [this](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-open-a-windows-command-prompt-in-my-console.html)

Answer (score 0):

The following may give you an idea:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // Since you are using eclipse, bin contains the compiled classes
    // This depends on your working directory. 
    File directory = new File("bin");

    // In my case, the main class is Game (in the default package)
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "java", "Game");

    // directory defined above
    pb.directory(directory);

    // The fun begins!
    pb.start();
}
```

The `Game` class containing only the following:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Game {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
        }
    }
}
```